# Помогите упростить вызов метода

Tags: python

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.state = 'Некоторая информация об игроке которая меняется в процессе игры'
    def changeState(self):
        '''изменить состояние state в зависимости от игровых обстоятельств'''
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player('Ivan')
        self.circumstances = 'Некоторые игровые обстоятельтсва'
```

Постарался максимально упростить пример. Вопрос такой. Мне приходится делать метод вот так: changeState(self, circumstances). Могут ли методы player получать доступ к информации circumstances без передачи circumstances в качестве параметра? А то вызов метода получается излишне сложным. Получается объекты player и circumstances находятся внутри одного объекта и не могут обращаться непосредственно ни к друг другу ни к своему родительскому объекту?

Comment: ttt = Game()
print(ttt.player.name)
print(ttt.circumstances)
или вы хотите из объекта self.player получить данные self.circumstances?

Comment: @inquirer , да, из объекта self.player получить данные self.circumstances, только так, чтобы не передавать self.circumstances как параметр

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю воспользоваться следующим способом

```
import functools
f=functools.partial(print,'one','two')
f('alfa')
#one two alfa
f()
#one two
```

то есть обернуть функцию другой функцией, которая будет передовать параметр по умолчанию